# Position of insertion cursor js

Tags: javascript

How can I get the X Y coordinate of where the insertion cursor is
(the vertical line that blinks when you are typing)?

I detected keypress using

```
function myKeyPress(e){
    var keynum;
    if(e.target.tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        console.log(e.target.selectionStart);
        console.log(e.target.tagName);
        e.target.value += "AAA";
        p.style.top = e.target.selectionStart;
        p.style.left = e.target.selectionEnd;
        p.value = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
        console.log(p, e.target.selectionStart, e.target.selectionEnd);
        if(window.event) { // IE                  
            keynum = e.keyCode;
        } else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                 
            keynum = e.which;
        }
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
    }
}
document.onkeypress = myKeyPress;
```

but e.target.selectionStart doesn't return the coordinates.

My end goal is to insert a div as a list beside or under the caret in order to have auto suggestion for text.

Comment: To what element are you looking for the x,y coords of the caret?

Comment: It's in a textarea